# Inner Urls not working on Linode

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

**I have below two routes**

```
Route::get('register', 
    array(
        'uses' =>  'Auth\Register\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm', 
        'as'   =>  'showRegistrationForm'
    )
);

Route::get('/', 
    array(
        'uses' =>  'Auth\Login\LoginController@showLoginForm', 
        'as'   =>  'showLoginForm'
    )
);
```

Both routes works perfectly on localhost. Then, I deployed the files on Linode server at path /var/www/html/adminapi2

I again checked above both urls. Login Url(default) works fine(http://50.116.5.82/adminapi2/public/) but url with route: showLoginForm gives 404 error(http://50.116.5.82/adminapi2/public/register)

AM I missing anything?

Comment: Are you sure those two lines are the only content of your routing file?

Comment: What server engine running on your Linode? Apache or nginx? It seems url rewrite not working on your server.

Comment: Apache is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem you are running laravel as subdirectory, to make url rewriting works, you should change `public/.htacces` file from:

```
...

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

...
```

to

```
...

RewriteRule ^ adminapi2/public/index.php [L]

...
```

Your `RewriteRule` should configured as subdirectory.

Hope it helps

Comment: I saw it works fine if I check route like this: http://50.116.5.82/adminapi2/public/index.php/register, I think, I am doing wrong deployment. Can you please tell where should I put the laravel code? Presently, it is deployed by making a directory called adminapi2 in /var/www/html and so the final path is /var/www/html/adminapi2

Comment: Maybe yout should change the `DocumentRoot` configuration of your apache to `/var/www/html/adminapi2/public`

Comment: no, I meant, should I put only the public files inside html and remaining files/folders inside www folder?

Comment: Normally when deploying laravel to server, we should change our `DocumentRoot` to `public` directory of Laravel. Laravel directory structure has been configured that only files inside `public` directory can be accessed by the browser. But if you wan't another aproach, may be you can try this way: https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e.